# Only the last place is getting displayed in the infowindow in google map apis

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I am trying to make a single page webapp for displaying markers on a list of places and their corresponding info Windows using knockoutjs. Following is the code.

```
<head>
    <title>Google maps</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href='css/style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="options-box">
            <h1>Liverpool Pubs and Bars - Anfield</h1>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <input id="filter-area" type="text" placeholder="Enter your favorite Pub">
                <input id="filter-button" type='button' value="Filter">
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <ul data-bind='foreach: allPlaces'>
                    <li data-bind='text: name'></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry,drawing&key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS code.

```
var ViewModel = function (googleMap, myPlaces, infoWindow) {

    var self = this;

    self.map = googleMap;
    self.allPlaces = [];
    self.markers = [];
    myPlaces.forEach(function(place) {
        newObj = new Place(place);
        title = newObj.name;
        console.log(title);
        // Getting the geocode for the place.
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': place.address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: self.map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    title: title
                });

                self.markers.push(marker);

                (function (marker, title) {
                     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
                         infoWindow.setContent(title);
                         infoWindow.open(self.map, marker);
                     });
                 })(marker, title);
            }
        });
        self.allPlaces.push(newObj);
    });
}

var Place = function(data) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.address = data.address;

}

var createMap = function () {
    var map;

    // Constructor creates a new map - only center and zoom are required.
    // Centering map at Anfield.
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 53.4308294, lng: -2.96083},
        mapTypeControl: false,
        zoom: 13
    });

    return map;
}

function initMap() {
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){

    // list of my places.
    var myPlaces = [
    {
        name: 'The Albert',
        address: '185 Walton Breck Rd, Liverpool L4 0RE, UK'
    },
    {
        name: 'Arkles',
        address: '77 Anfield Rd, Liverpool L4 0TJ, UK'
    },
    {
        name: 'The Sandon',
        address: '178-182 Oakfield Rd, Liverpool L4 0UH, UK'
    },
    {
        name: 'The Park Pub',
        address: '216-218 Walton Breck Rd, Liverpool L4 0RQ, UK'
    },
    {
        name: 'The Twelfth Man',
        address: '121 Walton Breck Rd, Liverpool L4 0RD, UK'
    }
    ];
    var googleMap = createMap();
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(googleMap, myPlaces, infoWindow))
});
}

function populateInfoWindow(marker, infowindow) {

    // Check to make sure the infowindow is not already opened on this marker.
    if (infowindow.marker != marker) {
        infowindow.marker = marker;
        infowindow.setContent('<div>' + marker.title + '</div>');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        // Make sure the marker property is cleared if the infowindow is closed.
        infowindow.addListener('closeclick',function(){
            infowindow.setMarker = null;
        });
    }
}
```

The rest of the map driven code is regular initMap function. The initMap function creates a infowindow, initializes a list of places with name and address attributes. And the google is initialized.

The markers are appearing correctly, though clicking on them opens the info window with only the name of last element.  Is it something related to JS closures? How can I implement an IFFE here. Would it solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, added var to the statements newObj and title and the problem was fixed.!!